# How do you span a Grid cell across rows, instead of columns?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Every tutorial you read online only talks about column spanning, and indeed, the documentation for Grid only contains a view modifier for column spanning, with `.gridCellColumns()`.

Is there a view modifier that makes a grid cell span multiple **rows**? For example, how would you span a vertical divider, instead of the horizontal, that is shown in the tutorial [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/grid#Multicolumn-cells)?

HStacks do not provide equal size to all their views, so it doesn't seem like an option. I could go for a custom layout with the `Layout` protocol, but that seems like a lot of work for something so small.

Comment: An ```HStack``` will provide equal width to all views if you apply ```.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)``` to every item.